# Site is loading HTML before CSS? No @import is being used

Tags: php, html, css, joomla

It happens for a fraction of a second every time I get into the site and the CSS is not cached.

Here is the link:

```
http://69.89.31.88/~intrasc1/index.php
```

All my CSS files are using the link tag and this started to happen right after I upgraded from joomla 1.5 to 2.5. Also the template was from 1.5 and I upgraded it too.

Comment: I'm struggling to see the problem here. I have looked in the browser console and don't see the HTML being loaded after the CSS.

Comment: Looks fine to me, have you tried it in different browsers to see if you get the same effect?

Comment: Have you tried a force refresh (CTRL + F5 on win) ? it might be that part of your page is cached from before the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

You have a very unusual setup there.  No scripts except for livezilla tracking and google analytics. Kudos.

The style that's being loaded last is `http://www.intras.com.do/livezilla/templates/style.css`, and is causing the flicker effect.  But the script is not in your markup, nor in any @import inside one of the other css files.

Only one possible cause is left: the "livezilla - tracking" script. If you open it, here's the inclusion of the css:

```
if(lz_overlay_chat_available)
{
    createCSSCheck("csschkoc");
    LazyLoad.css(lz_poll_server + "templates/overlays/chat/style.css", function (arg) {}, '');
...
```

Which dynamically loads the

```
http://www.intras.com.do/livezilla/templates/style.css
```

In order to fix the issue, simply include this style in your template header, or add it with `$document->addStyleSheet($url)`.

Since you've gone a long way optimizing the site and removing all scripts, why not take this as an opportunity and take the last step, join and minify all the css files into one?